# Oracle SQL - Efficient Join N Rows Per Match

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

The basic idea is to join two tables, let's call them `MYTABLE1` and `MYTABLE2` on a field `JOINID`.  There will be lots of matches per `JOINID` (one row from `MYTABLE1` corresponding to many rows in `MYTABLE2`, and for the purposes of testing, `MYTABLE1` has 50 rows), but we want to only select up to N matches per `JOINID` value.  I have seen lots of inefficient solutions, for example:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from MYTABLE1 t1 inner join
  (select MYTABLE2.*,
    row_number() over (partition by MYTABLE2.JOINKEY order by 1) as seqnum
  from MYTABLE2) t2
  on t1.joinkey = t2.joinkey and seqnum <= 2;
```

which takes over 5 minutes for me to run and returns less than 100 results, whereas something like

```
select t1.*, t2.* 
  from MYTABLE1 t1 inner join MYTABLE2 t2 on t1.JOINKEY = t2.JOINKEY
  where rownum <= 100;
```

returns 100 results in ~60 milliseconds.

(To be sure of the validity of these results, I selected a different test table and performed the second query above on a specific single `JOINKEY` until I got a result set with less than 100 results, meaning it did in fact search through all of `MYTABLE2`.  The total query time was 30 milliseconds.  Afterwards, I started the original query, but this time getting 50 joins per row of `MYTABLE1`, which again took over 5 minutes to complete.)

How can I approach this in a not-so-terribly-inefficient manner?

It seems so simple, all we need to do is go through the rows of `MYTABLE1` and matching the `JOINKEY` field to that of rows of `MYTABLE2`, moving on to the next row of `MYTABLE1` once we have matched the desired number for that row.

In the worst case scenario for my second example, we should have to spend 30ms searching through the full `TABLE2` per row of `TABLE1`, of which there are 50 rows, for a total execution time of 1.5 seconds.

Comment: You mentioned that MYTABLE1 has 50 rows.  
How many rows are in MYTABLE2?

Comment: Order of 10^8 .

Comment: Thanks Apollys.  That helps guage things.  Ok I'll try an experiment with that and maybe add something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call the below approach efficient by any means and it cheats a little and has some clunkiness, but it comes in under the 1500ms limit you provided so I'll add as something to consider.

This example cheats in that it compiles a `TYPE`, so it can table an anonymous function.

This approach just iteratively probes `MYTABLE2` with each `JOINKEY` from `MYTABLE1` using an anonymous subquery-factoring-clause function  and accumulates the results as it goes.

I don't know the real structure of the tables involved, so this example pretends `MYTABLE2` has one additional `CHAR` attribute called `OTHER_DATA` that is the target of the `SELECT`.

First, setup the test tables:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE1 (
  JOINKEY NUMBER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE MYTABLE2 (
  JOINKEY NUMBER NOT NULL,
  OTHER_DATA CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX MYTABLE2_I
  ON MYTABLE2 (JOINKEY);
```

Then add the test data.  50 rows to `MYTABLE1` and 100M rows to `MYTABLE2`:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE1
  SELECT LEVEL
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 51;

BEGIN
  <<COMMIT_LOOP>>
  FOR OUTER_POINTER IN 1..4000 LOOP
  <<DATA_LOOP>>
    FOR POINTER IN 1..10 LOOP
      INSERT INTO MYTABLE2
        SELECT
          JOINKEY, OTHER_DATA
        FROM
          (SELECT LEVEL AS JOINKEY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 51)
          CROSS JOIN
          (SELECT CHR(64 + LEVEL) AS OTHER_DATA FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 51);
    END LOOP DATA_LOOP;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP COMMIT_LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then gather stats...

Verify the table counts:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE1;
50        

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE2;
100000000
```

Then create a `TYPE` that includes the desired data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE JOINKEY_OTHER_DATA IS OBJECT (JOINKEY1 NUMBER, OTHER_DATA CHAR(1));
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE JOINKEY_OTHER_DATA_LIST IS TABLE OF JOINKEY_OTHER_DATA;
/
```

And then run a query that uses an anonymous subquery-factoring-block function that imposes a rowcount per `JOINKEY` to be returned.  In this first example, it fetches two `MYTABLE2` rows per `JOINKEY`:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

WITH FUNCTION FETCH_N_ROWS
(P_MATCHES_LIMIT IN NUMBER)
              RETURN JOINKEY_OTHER_DATA_LIST
              AS
              V_JOINKEY_OTHER_DATAS JOINKEY_OTHER_DATA_LIST;
BEGIN
  V_JOINKEY_OTHER_DATAS := JOINKEY_OTHER_DATA_LIST();
  FOR JOINKEY_POINTER IN (SELECT MYTABLE1.JOINKEY
                          FROM MYTABLE1)
  LOOP
    DECLARE
      V_MYTABLE2_JOINKEYS JOINKEY_OTHER_DATA_LIST;
    BEGIN
    SELECT JOINKEY_OTHER_DATA(MYTABLE2.JOINKEY, MYTABLE2.OTHER_DATA)
    BULK COLLECT INTO V_MYTABLE2_JOINKEYS
    FROM MYTABLE2 WHERE MYTABLE2.JOINKEY = JOINKEY_POINTER.JOINKEY
    FETCH FIRST P_MATCHES_LIMIT ROWS ONLY;
    V_JOINKEY_OTHER_DATAS := V_JOINKEY_OTHER_DATAS MULTISET UNION ALL V_MYTABLE2_JOINKEYS;
      END;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN V_JOINKEY_OTHER_DATAS;
END;
SELECT *
FROM TABLE (FETCH_N_ROWS(2));
/

SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

Results in:

```
SYSTIMESTAMP                            
18-APR-17 03.32.10.623056000 PM -06:00  

JOINKEY1  OTHER_DATA  
1         A           
1         B           
2         A           
2         B           
3         A           
3         B      
...
49        A           
49        B           
50        A           
50        B           


100 rows selected. 
SYSTIMESTAMP                            
18-APR-17 03.32.11.014554000 PM -06:00
```

By changing the number passed to `FETCH_N_ROWS`, different data volumens can be fetched with fairly consistent performance.

```
...
SELECT * FROM TABLE (FETCH_N_ROWS(13));
```

Returns:

```
...
50        K           
50        L           
50        M           
650 rows selected.
```

Comment: Nice, I too have decided to try a procedural approach; I will have to read over your solution once I have time to see if it makes sense to me.  Just one question: do you think it is impossible in non-procedural SQL, or just more difficult?

Comment: Thanks @Apollys I don't know if it's impossible to get a per-join stopkey in Oracle to do this kind of limiting. I've never come across it and I couldn't think of a way to approximate it, but it is an interesting idea.  If something like "INNER JOIN LIMIT 5" or whatever existed, it would be handy and drop the cost in situations like this one. If any questions about this approach just let me know. I didn't see a specific oracle version tagged, so I just used 12cR1 in this experiment.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your hard work on this question :)  Cheers alexgibbs!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the two queries.  The second query is simply returning whatever rows come first.  The second has to go through *all* the data to return anything.  A more apt comparison would use:

```
select . . .
from (select t1.*, t2.* 
      from MYTABLE1 t1 inner join
           MYTABLE2 t2
           on t1.JOINKEY = t2.JOINKEY
      order by t1.JOINKEY
     ) t1
where rownum <= 100;
```

This has to read all the data before returning anything so it is more analogous to using row number.

But, start with this query:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from MYTABLE1 t1 inner join
     (select MYTABLE2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t2.JOINKEY order by 1) as seqnum
      from MYTABLE2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.joinkey = t2.joinkey and seqnum <= 2;
```

For this query, you want an index on `MYTABLE2(JOINKEY)`.  If the `ORDER BY` has another key, that should be in the query as well.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point... I am comparing to the second query because it provides the functionality I require.  I could manually go through every row of `MYTABLE1` and get the results I need, how can I achieve this same result in a single query?